# TWIG: отложенные функции

Tags: функции, twig, php, symfony2

Есть ли возможность реализовать в шаблонах TWIG + Symfony2 отложенные функции?

Приблизительно вот так:

```
<title>{% printTitle('Дефолтовый заголовок') %}</title>
...
...
...
{% setTitle('Новый заголовок') %}
```

Понятно, что в данном случае лучше бы обойтись наследованием шаблонов или вообще архитектурно обойти этот костыль. Но интересует именно такой вариант.

Впрочем если это не реализовано на данный момент, то в какую сторону вообще стоит копать? Для начала реализуемо ли это в принципе?

Так например, я знаю успешную реализацию отложенных функций в битриксе. Принцип прост: весь вывод складывается в стек, любая функция отложенного типа прерывает текущий элемент стека, вставляет новый элемент с дефолтовым содержанием, и еще один новый элемент - продолжение вывода шаблона. Вызовы специальных функций изменяют содержание отложенного элемента. И после все элементы стека конкатенируются и результат выводится пользователю. Насколько сложно это реализовать в TWIG-е?

Comment: прошу прощения, если ошибаюсь: как я понял, SetTitle перезаписывает printTitle ?

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли. Есть идеи?)

Comment: Cделайте Title - глобальным перенменным, и чтобы printTitle ,setTitle печатали(присваивали значение, проверяя на условия, и .тд.)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через пользовательские функции, тот же самый стек можно на них реализовать. [Тут можешь посмотреть как они реализуются](http://x-twig.ru/blog/polzovatelskie_funktsii_v_twig/)